# Web API custom IContractResolver

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I implemented a custom IContractResolver so that I could dynamically filter out certain properties on an object from my Web API. As an example, the action GetEmployees will filter out the "Id" property of each employee returned.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    var ignoreList = new List<string> {"Id"};
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new JsonContractResolver(ignoreList);
    return db.Employees.AsEnumerable();
}
```

The problem is that in the same method, I would like to set the contract resolver back to its default value. Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    var defaultContractResolver = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
    var ignoreList = new List<string> {"Id"};
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new JsonContractResolver(ignoreList);
    // Serialize object
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = defaultContractResolver;
    // return serialized object
}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not the way you try it. You'll run in threading issues this way.

One way could be to alter your returned object to not contain the `Id`-property. Instead make a more specialized object. This is the way I'd go.

Alternatively you can return a `HttpResponseMessage` directly and set the content to whatever you like. But then you have to take care of serializing and content negation yourself.

Comment: So, just loop through the employees that were requested from the database and create a new list of specialized objects to be returned?

Comment: Yes. For special cases special data object. Personally I'm not a fan of returning database objects directly anyway (no matter if they're POCOs), I seperate those objects from DTO objects.